# Как динамически добавлять строки в GridPane?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Значит есть [тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977080/how-to-add-the-rows-dynamically-on-gridpane-in-java-fx) с примером.

В ней человеку нужно динамически добавлять в GridPane новые строки операясь на данный из файла. Мне нужно просто хотя бы создать новую строку в GridPane. Меня интересует, что нужно указывать вместо параметра *nodeThatYouWant*?

```
if(lineCounter > 1){
    gridPane.addRow(lineCounter-1, nodeThatYouWant);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите документацию - https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html. `nodeThatYouWant` - это один или более элементов (`Node`), которые по порядку будут разложены в ячейки внутри строки. Например, это могут быть `Label`-ы.

Comment: @Nofate,  .html [минимальная длина комментария 15 символов]

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо. http://joxi.ru/l2Z690qhwDXG62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Label labelName = new Label(getName());
    Label labelEvent = new Label(String.valueOf(getEvent()));
    Label labelGuide = new Label(String.valueOf(getGuide()));
    Label labelLost_points = new Label(String.valueOf(getLost_points()));
    Label labelCurrent_points = new Label(String.valueOf(getCurrent_points()));
    Label labelAll_Points = new Label(String.valueOf(getAll_points()));

    Node[] tempchild = {
        labelName,
        labelEvent,
        labelGuide,
        labelLost_points,
        labelCurrent_points,
        labelAll_Points
    };
GridPane.addRow(номердобавляемой строки, tempchild);
```